# Rails 4.2 Ruby 2.2.1 Spring won't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-spring

I just did a fresh install of rails using [RailsInstaller Ruby 2.1](https://s3.amazonaws.com/railsinstaller/Windows/railsinstaller-3.1.0.exe)

And after I did a bundle install and everything succeeded I tried to start up spring and got the following error:

```
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/sid.rb:33:in ``': No such file or directory
 - ps -p 1108 -o sess= (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/sid.rb:33:in `sid'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/sid.rb:39:in `pgid'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/server.rb:78:in `set_pgid'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/server.rb:34:in `boot'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/server.rb:14:in `boot'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Here is what my sid.rb file looks like

```
begin
  # If rubygems is present, keep it out of the way when loading fiddle,
  # otherwise if fiddle is not installed then rubygems will load all
  # gemspecs in its (futile) search for fiddle, which is slow.
  if respond_to?(:gem_original_require, true)
    gem_original_require 'fiddle'
  else
    require 'fiddle'
  end
rescue LoadError
end

module Spring
  module SID
    def self.fiddle_func
      @fiddle_func ||= Fiddle::Function.new(
        DL::Handle::DEFAULT['getsid'],
        [Fiddle::TYPE_INT],
        Fiddle::TYPE_INT
      )
    end

    def self.sid
      @sid ||= begin
        if Process.respond_to?(:getsid)
          # Ruby 2
          Process.getsid
        elsif defined?(Fiddle) and defined?(DL)
          # Ruby 1.9.3 compiled with libffi support
          fiddle_func.call(0)
        else
          # last resort: shell out
          `ps -p #{Process.pid} -o sess=`.to_i
        end
      end
    end

    def self.pgid
      Process.getpgid(sid)
    end
  end
end
```

I suppose that the that real error is that it can't get the sid here:

```
 if Process.respond_to?(:getsid)
      # Ruby 2
      Process.getsid
```

But I have no idea what to do about this. I am using spring 1.3.3 which is the latest version.

Thanks,

Comment: This seems like a bug with the spring gem so I also asked the authors about it [here](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/395). I will update if there is any progress.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, seems that spring is not supported on windows. Just re-read the [docs](https://github.com/rails/spring)

```
Spring makes extensive use of Process.fork, so won't be able to provide a speed up on platforms which don't support forking (Windows, JRuby).
```

Comment: Stackoverflow makes you wait 2 days :)